# how to make json reponse return {} instead of null

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing an API in ror using builder which return a list of items , this API would be consumed by the mobile devices.

when my list is empty I get a null in the tag, I need it to be {}, Please refer below for code

```
     xml.my_items{
     if @items.blank? 
        {}
     else 
       @items.each do |item|
         xml.item{
           xml.id(item.id)
           xml.name(item.name)
        }
      end
     end
     }
```

I get the response as

```
{"items":null}
```

I want it to be

```
{"items":{}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you want `[]` rather than `{}`? Anyway this code is generating XML, not JSON. You should just use `{todos: @items.map(&:name)}.to_json`

Comment: I am using the same .builder template for both json and xml request. 
There are more field that i pass to the request. updated the question